# Automate the creation of columns based on the value of other columns of a feature collection in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am working with a grid that has values for each year in the interval 2001-2022.  I need to create a function that allows me to do the same as the following function but in fewer lines of code:

```
   .map(function prcj(feature) {
  var d01 = ee.Number(feature.get('2001'));
  var d02 = ee.Number(feature.get('2002'));
  var d03 = ee.Number(feature.get('2003'));
  var d04 = ee.Number(feature.get('2004'));
  var d05 = ee.Number(feature.get('2005'));
  var d06 = ee.Number(feature.get('2006'));
  var d07 = ee.Number(feature.get('2007'));
  var d08 = ee.Number(feature.get('2008'));
  var d09 = ee.Number(feature.get('2009'));
  var d10 = ee.Number(feature.get('2010'));
  var d11 = ee.Number(feature.get('2011'));
  var d12 = ee.Number(feature.get('2012'));
  var d13 = ee.Number(feature.get('2013'));
  var d14 = ee.Number(feature.get('2014'));
  var d15 = ee.Number(feature.get('2015'));
  var d16 = ee.Number(feature.get('2016'));
  var d17 = ee.Number(feature.get('2017'));
  var d18 = ee.Number(feature.get('2018'));
  var d19 = ee.Number(feature.get('2019'));
  var d20 = ee.Number(feature.get('2020'));
  var d21 = ee.Number(feature.get('2021'));
  var d22 = ee.Number(feature.get('2022'));
  
  return feature.set({prcj_01: d01.multiply(100).divide(400),
                      prcj_02: d02.multiply(100).divide(400),
                      prcj_03: d03.multiply(100).divide(400),
                      prcj_04: d04.multiply(100).divide(400),
                      prcj_05: d05.multiply(100).divide(400),
                      prcj_06: d06.multiply(100).divide(400),
                      prcj_07: d07.multiply(100).divide(400),
                      prcj_08: d08.multiply(100).divide(400),
                      prcj_09: d09.multiply(100).divide(400),
                      prcj_10: d10.multiply(100).divide(400),
                      prcj_11: d11.multiply(100).divide(400),
                      prcj_12: d12.multiply(100).divide(400),
                      prcj_13: d13.multiply(100).divide(400),
                      prcj_14: d14.multiply(100).divide(400),
                      prcj_15: d15.multiply(100).divide(400),
                      prcj_16: d16.multiply(100).divide(400),
                      prcj_17: d17.multiply(100).divide(400),
                      prcj_18: d18.multiply(100).divide(400),
                      prcj_19: d19.multiply(100).divide(400),
                      prcj_20: d20.multiply(100).divide(400),
                      prcj_21: d21.multiply(100).divide(400),
                      prcj_22: d22.multiply(100).divide(400)
  });
```

I guess it should be a function inside the function I generated, but I can't figure out how to do it. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In `map()`, you can use `ee.List.iterate()` to set the new property on the feature for each year. From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-list-iterate):

> Iterate an algorithm over a list. The algorithm is expected to take two objects, the current list item, and the result from the previous iteration or the value of first for the first iteration.

```
var mapped = features.map(function (feature) {
  return ee.Feature(
    ee.List.sequence(1, 22).iterate(
      function (i, feature) {
        i = ee.Number(i)
        feature = ee.Feature(feature)
        var key = ee.String('prcj_').cat(i.format('%02d'))
        var oldValue = feature.getNumber(i.add(2000).format('%d'))
        var value = oldValue.divide(4)
        return feature.set(key, value)
      },
      feature
    )
  )
})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/fbe027768e79b14be559bcee4f85c57f